# SQL Merge Data into Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table set up that tracks changes to a user's account.

It has `ID`, `UserAccountNo`, `OldVal`, `NewVal`, `ChangeColumnName` columns.

I have a query set up similar to this:

```
    Select case 
    when ChangeColumnName = 'Address1' then NewVal else '' end as Address1,
    when ChangeColumnName = 'Address2' then NewVal else '' end as Address2,
    when ChangeColumnName = 'City' then NewVal else '' end as City,
    when ChangeColumnName = 'State' then NewVal else '' end as State,
    when ChangeColumnName = 'Zip' then NewVal else '' end as Zip,
    when ChangeColumnName = 'Phone' then NewVal else '' end as Phone
    from table
    Where (Conditions)
```

If someone changes the city, state, and zip, there are 3 entries in the table. When I run this query, I get 3 rows returned. I would like to get them all together in one row, and haven't been able to figure out how.

When I tried using groupby with max(colname) as suggested in other posts, it gives the max NewVal value, so I end up with email addresses in Phone columns.

Is this possible to do in SQL 2008 without reforming the entire table?

Comment: Do you need to transform rows into columns? or into comma separated values? or anything else? show expected results

Comment: I want all changes shown in one row. So if you change your city, state, and zip, it is in one row instead of 3.

Comment: What column(s) do you have that would identify those three change rows as belonging to a single change?

Comment: The account number. We don't have to worry about if someone changes the address 3-4-5 times because we're only bringing back certain records. This is all taken care of in the where clause.

Comment: Look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/289836/7

Comment: @Bigdaddyduergar Have you tried? is this approach working for you?

Comment: I'm actually using the suggestion that PaulF made below. It works beautifully. thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
create table #t
(
id int,
userAccountNo int,
oldVal varchar(255),
newVal varchar(255),
changeColName varchar(255)
);

insert #t values (1, 1, '123 main st', '123 s. main st.', 'Address1'),
  (2, 1, 'Springville', 'Springfield', 'City'),
  (3, 1, 'Springfield', 'N. Springfield', 'City'),
  (4, 2, '12345', '12346', 'Zip');

with U as (select distinct userAccountNo from #t),
    Address1 as (select userAccountNo, newVal from #t as T1 where changeColName = 'Address1' and id >=ALL
    (select id from #t as T2 where T1.userAccountNo = T2.userAccountNo and T1.changeColName = T2.changeColName)),
    City as (select userAccountNo, newVal from #t as T1 where changeColName = 'City' and id >=ALL
    (select id from #t as T2 where T1.userAccountNo = T2.userAccountNo and T1.changeColName = T2.changeColName)),
    Zip as  (select userAccountNo, newVal from #t as T1 where changeColName = 'Zip' and id >=ALL
    (select id from #t as T2 where T1.userAccountNo = T2.userAccountNo and T1.changeColName = T2.changeColName))
select
U.userAccountNo,
A1.newVal as [Address1],
C.newVal as [City],
Z.newVal as [Zip]
from
U
full outer join Address1 as A1 on U.userAccountNo = A1.userAccountNo
full outer join City as C on U.userAccountNo = C.userAccountNo
full outer join Zip as Z on U.userAccountNo = Z.userAccountNo;
```

And if it seems to work it can be extended to cover all of your columns.

Comment: It took some tweaking with the database format that we have, but this works beautifully! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use pivot command, use this script and let me know :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('_temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE _temp

SELECT *
    INTO _temp
FROM (
        Select 'PostalCode' AS ChangeColumnName, '95100' AS NewValue UNION ALL
        Select 'City' AS ChangeColumnName, 'Argenteuil' AS NewValue UNION ALL
        Select 'LastName' AS ChangeColumnName, 'DAOUI' AS NewValue UNION ALL
        Select 'FirstName' AS ChangeColumnName, 'Youssef' AS NewValue UNION ALL
        Select 'Phone Number' AS ChangeColumnName, '00212 6 60 93 36 12' AS NewValue 
 ) AS Temp

    DECLARE  @v_ListeColonnes           VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
            ,@v_sql                     VARCHAR(MAX) = ''           

    SELECT @v_ListeColonnes         = @v_ListeColonnes + ',' + QUOTENAME(ChangeColumnName)
    FROM _temp

    IF LEN(@v_ListeColonnes) > 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_ListeColonnes = RIGHT(@v_ListeColonnes, LEN(@v_ListeColonnes)-1)
            SET @v_sql  =    'SELECT '+CHAR(13)
                            +'      ' + @v_ListeColonnes + ' '+CHAR(13)
                            +'FROM _temp '+CHAR(13)
                            +'PIVOT (MAX(NewValue) '+CHAR(13)
                            +'  FOR ChangeColumnName in(' + @v_ListeColonnes + ')) as pvt        '+CHAR(13)
            EXEC(@v_sql)
        END

IF OBJECT_ID('_temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE _temp
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you need one row and one column for all changes, it works for any number of columns changed.

**[SQL FIDDLE TEST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90207/1)**

```
declare @changes as varchar(max)
declare @UserAccountNo int

set @UserAccountNo=1
set @changes=''

select @changes=@changes + ColumnChanged +'-'    
from changes where UserAccountNo=@UserAccountNo

select @UserAccountNo 'UserAccountNo', @changes 'Changes'
```